# Captcha for Japanese and Chinese?

Tags: internationalization, captcha

Normally I use Recaptcha for all captcha purposes, but now I'm building a website that is translated into Chinese and Japanese, among other languages. I'd like to make the captcha as accessible to those users as possible. Even if they can read and type English characters (which is not necessarily the case), often times even I as an English-speaker have had trouble figuring out what the word in Recaptcha has to be.

One good solution I've seen (from Google) is to use numbers instead of text. Are there other good solutions? Is there a reliable free captcha service out there such as Recaptcha that offers this option?

Answer (score 3):

The Chinese and Japanese both use a keyboard with Latin characters on. The Chinese input their 1000s of characters via Pinyin (Romanized Chinese) and so they are very familiar with all the same letters that you and I are. Therefore, whatever you are using for English speaking people can also be used for them.

PS - I know this is an answer to an old post, but I'm hoping this answer will help anyone who comes here with the same question.

Comment: Yep, 100%. However the reason I asked this question long ago was mostly not that I doubt users don't have a means of entering Pinyin or Romaji, but that it can be really difficult to guess words from a language that you don't know (especially if they are mangled beyond recognition even for an English-speaker). So the numbered-solution is good (but possibly not strong enough), but from a UI/UX viewpoint maybe there are even better language-specific or picture-based CAPTCHAs out there?

Comment: @HermanSchaaf, any Chinese, Japanese (or other) person using a computer will be very familiar with the romanized characters because they are the means by which they input their own characters into the computer. The only Chinese/Japanese people that might be confused by distorted roman characters are those who are computer illiterate (and even then they are normally taught pinyin/romaji as children anyway) and hence this is not really an issue.

Comment: Though Yahoo! Japan does in fact show a [captcha with hiragana](http://i.imgur.com/BPZVDT0.png), but please just don't.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem in the past, I resolved the issue by using the following CAPTCHA which uses a numerical validation:

http://www.tipstricks.org/

However, this may not be the best solution for you, so here is an extensive list of different CAPTCHAs you might want to consider (most of them are text based, but some use alternative methods such as numerical expressions):

http://captcha.org/

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, that was quite useful. The captchas at www.tipstricks.org are in line with what I'm looking for, but sadly are only for ASP and not offered as a service (it also looks reasonably easy to crack, especially given only numbers). captcha.org also has some interesting captchas, but mostly for ASP (I use Django) and none that I could find that fits what I'm looking for.